# Why there is a mWaitingRequests in RequestQueue in Volley

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-volley

I know that **mWaitingRequest** keeps the requests that has the same **cacheKey**, when a Request is finished, the requests with the same **cacheKey** will be added to the **mCacheQueue**.

But I don't think this is necessory, why not just add the request with the same cacheKey to the mCacheQueue directly?

I just search google, but don't get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because then there will no cache for them and all will go to the networkqueue and u dont want that

Answer (score 0):

> the requests with the same cacheKey will be added to the mCacheQueue

No the request is only added if it must be cached, take a look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/RequestQueue.java#286) again:

```
<T> void finish(Request<T> request) {
        ...

        if (request.shouldCache()) {
            synchronized (mWaitingRequests) {
                String cacheKey = request.getCacheKey();
                Queue<Request<?>> waitingRequests = mWaitingRequests.remove(cacheKey);
                if (waitingRequests != null) {
                    if (VolleyLog.DEBUG) {
                        VolleyLog.v("Releasing %d waiting requests for cacheKey=%s.",
                                waitingRequests.size(), cacheKey);
                    }
                    // Process all queued up requests. They won't be considered as in flight, but
                    // that's not a problem as the cache has been primed by 'request'.
                    mCacheQueue.addAll(waitingRequests);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> why not just add the request with the same cacheKey to the mCacheQueue
>   directly?

First you should note that the server determines the caching policy, for example the server may not let you cache the data and set cache field of `http header` to something like:

```
cache-control: private, max-age=0, no-cache
```

that means every new request to the same `URL`can have a different response, can have a new response, that means the server response can change any time and must not be cached. Now if the user wants to cache the response and has made multiple requests each request may have a new response, so for simplicity if the user wants to cache the data, every request must dispatch to  `NetworkDispatcher`.